# Extra slash in urlManager rules

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I'm trying to map `services/v2/` to `servicesV2`.

I tried:

```
'services/v2' => 'servicesV2',
```

And I tried:

```
'services/v2/' => 'servicesV2/',
```

And:

```
'services/v2/<action:\w+>' => 'servicesV2/<action:\w+>',
```

And I got an error:

> The system is unable to find the requested action "v2".

Answer (score 0):

Did you put it on the begin of the array?

```
'rules'     => array(
                'services/v2'                            => 'servicesV2',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'              => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```